# scroll on top magnific popup

Tags: jquery, scrolltop, magnific-popup

iam have a button to scroll on top when page scroll to bottom. But when magnific popup ajax run button not firing and cannot scroll modal to top. how to fix it ?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.scroll-top-wrapper').addClass('show'); //button show
    } else {
        $('.scroll-top-wrapper').removeClass('show'); //button hide
    }
});
```

scroll top function :

```
function scrollToTop() {
    verticalOffset = typeof(verticalOffset) != 'undefined' ? verticalOffset : 0;
    element = $('body');
    offset = element.offset();
    offsetTop = offset.top;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: offsetTop
    }, 500, 'linear');
}
```

magnific popup code :

```
$(document).on('click', '#detailkp', function(event) {
    popup.open({
        items: {
            src: base_url + 'ekp/detail'
        },
        type: 'ajax',
        ajax: {
            settings: {
                data: {
                    'key': function() {
                        return $('#table-kp tr.success').attr('id')
                    }
                },
                type: 'POST'
            }
        },
        closeOnContentClick: false,
        closeOnBgClick: false,
        enableEscapeKey: true
    });
});
```

you can try it on http://simponi-asn.info/ekp
and put 196204071981032002 to seacrh and click Detail button to run modal